# Deleting ith-jth character on every line in vim?

Tags: regex, unix, text, command, vi

I'm currently trying to streamline how I edit my files, and I need to figure out a way to delete the 2nd-10th character of each line, preserving the first character of each line.

I know you can delete the first N characters of every line with :%s/^.{0,N}// , but I don't know how to make the first match to be second character of the line, instead of just the beginning of the line as expressed with ^

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any other questions that helped me with this.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you need to remove nine characters beginning with the second char on each line.

You may use

```
:%s/^.\zs.\{9\}//
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of  a line
- `.` - any one char
- `\zs` - "lookbehind" alternative, dropping the text already matched so far
- `.\{9\}` - any nine chars.

Comment: Your demo is important for me, so please don't forget it, please.

Comment: @YasserKhalil If you find a Vim online regex tester, I will add. However, the above regex is equivalent to a PCRE pattern like [`^.\K.{9}`](https://regex101.com/r/X4lNxt/1).

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are other conditions you can try

```
:%norm l9x
```

Clarification: run a "normal command" on every line that is "go one character to the right and delete nine characters".

*It's a small 'L' in front of the '9', not a digit.* ;-)